# Tensorflow and keras: No gradients provided for any variable

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensor, loss-function

i am pretty new to tensorflow and keras, i try to create my custom loss function:

```
def loss_function(reward, next_q_values, q_values):
    target_i = reward + discount_factor * np.max(next_q_values)
    loss = tf.pow((target_i-np.max(q_values)),2)
    return tf.reduce_mean(loss)
```

called with:

```
tensor_state = tf.expand_dims(states[indices[0]], axis = 0)
q_val = model.predict(tensor_state)
q_update(states[indices[0]], taken_actions_g[indices[0]], rewards_g[indices[0]], q_val[0])
if (indices[0] != indices[31]):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        next_tensor_state = tf.expand_dims(states[i+1], axis = 0)
        next_q_values = model(next_tensor_state)
        loss = loss_function(rewards_g[i], next_q_values, q_val)
gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))
```

But if shows me this error:

```
No gradients provided for any variable: (['conv2d_156/kernel:0', 'conv2d_156/bias:0', 'conv2d_157/kernel:0', 'conv2d_157/bias:0', 'conv2d_158/kernel:0', 'conv2d_158/bias:0', 'dense_104/kernel:0', 'dense_104/bias:0', 'dense_105/kernel:0', 'dense_105/bias:0'],). Provided `grads_and_vars` is ((None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_156/kernel:0' shape=(8, 8, 1, 32) dtype=float32,
```

Do yout know how can i solve it? I have tried to see other questions but i haven't found a solution yet

**EDIT:**
This is my model:

```
inputs = Input(shape=(84,84,1))
lay1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, [8, 8], strides=4, activation='relu')(inputs)
lay2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, [4, 4], strides=2, activation='relu')(lay1)
lay3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, [3, 3], strides=1, activation='relu')(lay2)
lay4 = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(lay3)
lay5 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu')(lay4)
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(actions, activation='linear')(lay5)
```

It is strange because if i use as loss function for example this:

```
tf.keras.losses.mean_squared_error
```

it works without any problem.
I have tried also without np functions but the result is the same

Comment: Share your model and dummy data.

Comment: You cannot use numpy functions in a loss, you need to only use keras backend functions or tf functions.

Comment: I have edited the question to reply to both of you